# Single Sign On Error "Missing Portal_Id Attribute"

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I have a customer with an Enterprise edition org. We are implementing single sing on in a sandbox environment.

They have a home grown, in-house IDP (SAML 2.0) using Windows Server R2.

When we test a sample SAML assertion using the SAML Validator in the org we receive all green responses EXCEPT for "13. Looking for Portal and Organization Id, If provided".  The response in red for this is "Missing portal_id attribute" and in green "found organization_id attribute: {id}".

I understand that the portal_id attribute is for portals/communities specifically. Again, this is an Enterprise Edition org there are no portals and/or communities.

After some additional research, I found that you can choose to specify UserType (Standard, Portal, Site, etc.). If anyone is familiar with testing SAML on http://axiomsso.herokuapp.com/SamlIdpHome.action - you know that this is one of the selection options in the generate SAML response form.

We added the following to the assertion in attempt to specify the User Type.

STANDARD

In short, we are still receiving the error that the portal_id is not specified. Again, the confusion being we are configuring SSO for an EE org.

I have submitted a case to salesforce, they are having a hard time finding any documentation to further define the error or coming up with a solution for the issue.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For additional clarification we are implementing SP-initiated SSO